# Loading video is slow while loading data asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, windows-store-apps

I'm making a media player in .NET and I have a question of optimization.

I'm loading the user library browsing some folders. Once I find a new file, I update a List bound in a view, so the view is refreshed, everything is supposed to be asynchronous since I'm using the Async methods from .NET framework.

The problem is that when I click on a video while the library is still loading, it takes a lot of time to load and to start (like if it was waiting for the library to finish loading).

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening. Is it that the UI thread receives to many requests ?

If you need some code I can provide it but I don't know what part would be useful to you to locate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the library is still loading, it's doing a lot of disk access. That's going to interfere with loading the video because the disk head will seek to load part of the video, then seek to load more of the library, back to the video, etc.

You might consider setting a flag that tells the library loader to pause loading the library until the video is loaded and starts playing. Then the loader can continue working as the video plays.